# PHP task schedular script

Tags: php, mysql, cron

Hello all I am using script http://www.phpjobscheduler.co.uk/ for scheduling task on my server. I know about CRON jobs but i do not want to use CRON or MYSQL events. The script, i am using seems not working properly. is there any other script or library that execute scheduled task or execute on a specific time interval.

Comment: Is there ANY reason for not using CRONS? Infact, this script does nothing else.

Comment: @Y U NO WORK I am using shared server and there time setting is not matching with my country time zone.

Comment: Hi, this is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522698/issues-with-strftime-in-php